# conversion printing app from landscape to portrait mode

Tags: applications, printing

I often work just with the smartphone (Galaxy Note 3, Android Kitkat 4.4, no root) without any computer.

**After opening a landscape powerpoint-presentation with the smartphone, I want to print it in portrait mode (2 slides per page). Is there any solution?**

If there is no direct printer app with Remote Print it would also be very nice if there would exist a conversion app to save a conversed ppp in portrait mode as a new pdf. I'm searching since several months and would be so thankful and happy if there would be a solution!

Comment: I don't think there's an "on-board solution". There are [several printing apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=10) available, maybe one of those offers what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best apps for your (=my) aimis the app "Samsung Mobile Print".

1. Select 2 Up
2. Print it to your android device (use Google Cloud_Printer)
3. Wait a couple of minutes until your android device will download the new document (unfortunately this solutions converts colors to black/white, but for me it's okay)
4. Send the downloaded PDF to a normal Google-Cloud-Print or Remote-Print-App!

That's it!